# How do I check if the entered value is present anywhere in a file, then print it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def uniqueFileSearch(): 
    pupilEntered2 = input("Please enter the pupil ID:  \n")
    with open("pupilInformation.txt" , "r")as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith(pupilEntered2):
                print(line)
```

I want to check if the `pupilEntered2` value is present anywhere in the file and print it, not just the first line.

Here is a brief example of what the file is like:

```
Naomi65, Heron, 12, f
John34, Ashley, 11, m
```

Naomi is the first line in the code so it doesn't print any other lines except hers.

Comment: Does this code not do that? It looks fine to me (except for the missing `else` block). Please provide a [mre]. BTW welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: No it only prints the line if the first line in the file begins with pupilEntered2, however I used a different line for every pupil's line of information. Also yes there is more to the else block, I just cut it out as it was irrelevant.

Comment: @GogoGT Sorry, forgot to clarify before, your [mre] needs to include all inputs to the program (namely the pupil ID and contents of pupilInformation.txt) and a minimal version of your code (so either fill in the `else` block or remove it), plus a description of the issue (what is it supposed to do, what it does instead).

Comment: Oh okay, thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have seems to work for me and prints all lines starting with the search term. The name to search for must be at the beginning of the line.

If you want to search anywhere within a line, you only need a small change:

```
def uniqueFileSearch(): 
    pupilEntered2 = input("Please enter the pupil ID:  \n")
    with open("pupilInformation.txt" , "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            if pupilEntered2 in line:
                print(line)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, sorry it was such a simple question I'm just uneducated in most areas of python. This is precisely what I wanted, thanks again.

Comment: @BenKeez If this answer solves your problem, please consider marking it as accepted. I’m only writing this as you’re new on SO - welcome by the way!